# Bool Value not work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to animated my button up and down. When I am using Objective-C it works, but, when I am using Swift the bool value shows nil instead of false or true. I am new to Swift. Please help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var dd:UIButton!
    var isShown:Bool?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
@IBAction func touch()
{
println(self.isShown)
    if (self.isShown==false)
    {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.dd.frame=CGRectMake(35.0, 60, self.dd.frame.size.width, self.dd.frame.size.height)
       self.isShown=true
    })
    }
        else
        {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.dd.frame=CGRectMake(55.0, 130, self.dd.frame.size.width, self.dd.frame.size.height)
                self.isShown=false
            })
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why have you declared `isShown` as a `Bool?` rather than a `Bool` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

```
var isShown:Bool?
```

As a result of the statement above, the `isShown` variable is an optional `Bool` because there is an `?` following the `Bool`. This means that your `isShown` property may be `nil` or it may have a value.

However, in your code, **the `isShown` property is not initialized to any value.** Realize that Swift does not default the `Bool` to false like some other languages. As a result, you have to explicitly set the value of your `isShown` property to avoid it from being nil.

For example, you can do the following to initialize your property when it is declared:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var dd:UIButton!
    var isShown:Bool = false
    ...
}
```

You may also handle the initialization in other ways (for example, by assigning the value in the `viewDidLoad` function).

Read about Swift [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) since the concept does not exist in Objective C and it will help you understand how to handle your property.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize bool variable in viewDidLoad

```
isShown = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set bool value set bool value before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should directly initialized bool with value false.

Like this :-

```
var isShown : Bool = false
```

Hope this helps.